# Importing a JAR into Android Studio 2.2

Tags: java, android, groovy

I'm trying to import a JAR that I made in Groovy into an Android Studio 2.2 project and all the instructions I can find say to just add it under Project Structure -> app -> Dependencies.  I did this and it's still not letting me use the imported JAR.  I've imported JAR files from Groovy into other Java projects in Eclipse.  Did something change in Android Studio 2.2 that changes how you're supposed to do this?

[image]

Comment: Did you import your libs's package?

Comment: The default Gradle file compiles all Jars that are places into the `libs` folder. No IDE settings need touched

Answer (score 0):

I thinnk this step help You

1 ) Put the  jar (in my case, yourJar-2.2.4.jar) into the libs folder.

2)  Right click it and hit 'Add as library'.

3) Ensure that compile files('libs/yourJar-2.2.4.jar') is in your    build.gradle file (or compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') if you are using many jar files).

4) Do a clean build (you can probably do this fine in Android Studio, but to make sure I navigated in a terminal to the root folder of my app and typed gradlew clean. I'm on Mac OS X, the command might be different on your system.

5) Clean Project.

6) Run.

May be it,s Working

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out but I'm still not sure why it works.  I changed the package name of the JAR to match the Android project.  My Android project is com.johnwstanford.simplegps and I originally just called the JAR package SimpleGpsOutputFormatter.  I changed it to com.johnwstanford.simplegps.SimpleGpsOutputFormatter and for some reason, that made it work.  Anyone know why that would make a difference?

Comment: Did you import that in your Activity ?!?!?!?
import com.johnwstanford.simplegps.SimpleGpsOutputFormatter;
it should get imported automatically but sometimes it sucks